# How to use azure devops in Xamarin.Forms project?

Tags: c#, git, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, version-control

I am new to azure devops.

**Short Question**

I am seeing 7000 files(all dll and resource files) to commit when I want to commit only 5-10 cs and xaml files. Any leads please ?

**Background**

Few days back, I pushed my project in the remote repository but I was not clear about `Branch` concept. I have 15 pages and ViewModels respective to them. Every time I go to Changes tab in Team Explorer, I see thousands of files to commit(Includes all kind of dlls and resource files).

As I and my team was not clear about branch concept, we would `Stage` every .cs file and then commit and commit those staged files. And as we can't push our files without pulling changes from remote repo, I would mark all other dll files as stash and then pull from remote and then push my files.

If I commit all files or by mistake any of my team member clicks commit all then it would give me conflicts for thousand files(those dlls and resource fiels). So I found this way. But after some research I clear my concepts about branch and started creating branch for new tasks. but at the time of commit, its again showing 7000 files ready to commit.

I tried deleting bin obj folders and then tried to commit but it would give other users thousands of conflicts.

What shall I do ? I am not getting help anywhere on the internet for this

Thanks

Comment: You could check the doc from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xamarin?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml .

Comment: use gitgignore to exclude bin/obj from your commits - https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: and this appears to be a basic source code management issue, nothing specifically to do with Xamarin